# Old Account giving me issues in chat

Tags: support, bug, chat, user-accounts

I had an old account that I created using an email. However, I have recently tried to not use my email for logging in places as it is a google account and privacy and all that.

So, I was logged in on my gmail, and I decided to drop into Stack Exchange for a tad. I logged into my SE account (Ask Ubuntu, Stack Overflow, RPi Beta) and then went into chat. This is where the issue began.

I'm logged in currently as my regular user (RPi Awesomeness - PLEASE DON'T TOUCH THIS ONE!), but when I go to chat, I am my old user https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176286/user2176286, but when I go to the user page I'm obviously *not* logged in as that user (no user account controls.)

This is rather annoying, as I can't log into my old account to delete it! If my old account could be deleted, that would be great!

**EDIT**
Just confirmed that I cannot log into my old account via my e-mail. If my [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176286/user2176286) could be deleted (the user2176286 one, NOT RPi Awesomeness) that would be great :D